# Updating to Version 4.5 bumped my "main sidebar" widget out of place

Tags: widgets, updates, formatting, screen-layout

I updated to the newest version of word press and it changed my home screen. Essentially it shifted my text to the right and as a result shifted my "main sidebar" widget downward to now begin below the body of text. The main text body also overlaps the widget cutting off the top left corner. I'll note that we are using a custom theme generated by someone in the organization other than myself.

Here is a before and after:

[image: esa SE b4 & aftr]

**What's happened and how do I fix it?**

**UPDATE**: I visually noticed that the width of the white space margin around my text has grown larger (essentially shrinking my usable space). Perhaps this is the underlying problem? Was that just a part of upgrading to 4.5? I should probably start there -- Where/how do I change the width of the white space on the page?

**UPDATE2:** I actually also noticed 2 other changes to my page: 1. The font size of the heading got much larger. 2. If I change the layout to right-column oriented, the widget still floats down below -- this owuld suggest to me that the widget code itself also changed...

How do I revert the listed issues to previous formatting so that the website works as it should?

Comment: Without seeing any code, it's pretty hard to say what's happening.

Comment: Had any modifications to WordPress itself been made?

Comment: @Tom I didn't make any modifications. Also, it appears (visually) that the issue might be that the margins within the border of my white space have been expanded...perhaps this is the underlying problem? Was that just a part of upgrading to 4.5? Where/how do I change the width of the white space on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue and will be taken care of soon, assuming you are using the "Twenty Eleven" theme: [see this link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/read-this-first-wordpress-45-master-list).

The bundled Twenty Eleven theme has some styling issues for pages with sidebars [(See Trac ticket #36510)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36510)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like some people have created some workaround patches. Hopefully a true update for Twenty Eleven comes soon!

Comment: Follow that ticket, I am sure they will patch it. It is likely for 4.5.1 within the next few weeks.

Comment: This is now fixed in WP 4.5.1 which is out today.